# Magento - How to Login with “Secondary Email” customer attribute?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

How would a customer be able to login with both their primary email address they signed up with as well as a Secondary email address customer attribute field?  (I’ve created a customer attribute text field secondary_email).

Assuming it has something to do with customerEntity and would be similair to what people have been doing to get usernames to work:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Sylvain_Raye/extension/7928/diglin_username

or

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/195573/P15/

I just need for customers to have 1 single password, but be able to use an alternate email address specified within their account if they want.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Magento is no different from almost all other PHP-based frameworks in that it has a serial flow of execution. Thinking from a request flow standpoint, an entry point to suss out your requirement would be the class which handles the login form POST. You can see this in the [rendered source in your browser](https://demo.magentocommerce.com/customer/account/login): `action="https://demo.magentocommerce.com/customer/account/loginPost/"`.

The above URI resolves to the method `Mage_Customer_AccountController::loginPostAction()`. In there one finds typical login logic for a login controller action: is user logged in? is the user posting in login data? is the the login data valid? and so forth. This quickly points to the customer session model, `Mage_Customer_Model_Session`, particularly to the `authenticate()` method. In this method is a call to `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->loadByEmail()`, which gets us to Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Model->loadByEmail()`.

At this point, we know that we can rewrite the resource model and change its `loadByEmail()` to handle lookup of a secondary email method (messy & obtrusive). We could also rewrite and change `Mage_Customer_Model_Session->authenticate()`, providing some pre-processing to first load the customer record by secondary email, then extract the main email and allow things to proceed as normal.

```
//rewritten authenticate method
public function authenticate($username,$password) {
    $customer = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('secondary_email',$username)
                    ->getFirstItem();

    //check we found customer record by secondary email
    if ($customer->getId()) {
        parent::authenticate($login,$customer->getEmail());
    }
    else {
        parent::authenticate($username,$password)
    }
}
```

I've not really looked into the above snippet, nor would I vouch for its security, but hopefully this demonstrates the process by which one can answer these types of questions using awareness of the framework. This may not be a bad starting point; with something similar in the configured class rewrite plus a setup script to add the `secondary_email` attribute, this should be quick to implement.

**A note worth mentioning:**

It's also possible to accomplish this by observing the runtime-constructed `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_loginpost` event (see `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::preDispatch()`). While it is generally advisable to use the event observe system to effect functional rewrites when possible, this would be quite unintuitive and the messiest option of all.